# Finding all page IDs for URL in XML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the structure of an XML backup I am working with. I've written some code that will get all URLs from the XML - is there a way I can then, for each URL, traverse back up the XML and find the page ID (second tag in the XML structure below) which it appears on?

```
<page>
 <id></id>
 <name></name>
 <description>&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; target=&quot;_self&quot;&gt;LINK&lt;/a&gt;</description>
 <boxes>
  <box>
  </box>
 </boxes>
</page>
```

Update:

```
 <page>
 <id></id>
 <name></name>
 <description></description>
 <url></url>
 <boxes>
  <box>
   <id></id>
   <name></name>
   <type></type>
   <column></column>
   <position></position>
   <hidden></hidden>
   <created></created>
   <updated></updated>
   <assets>
    <asset>
     <id></id>
     <name></name>
     <type></type>
     <description></description>
     <url/>
     <owner>
      <id></id>
      <email></email>
      <first_name></first_name>
      <last_name></last_name>
     </owner>
     <map_id></map_id>
     <position></position>
     <created></created>
     <updated></updated>
    </asset>
   </assets>
  </box>
 </boxes>
</page>
```

Comment: and where is the `url` on that structure?

Comment: The URLs are within the description boxes.

Comment: can you update your question with the full structure?

Comment: Have edited in how a link typically appears.

Comment: It appears to me that it would be easier to read through the xml and capture pairs of ids and urls together.

Comment: That's essentially what I want to do. For each page in the XML, get the page ID and a list of all URLs found within the description box.

Comment: nobody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up a file of xml by replicating what you provided in your question and putting in some ids.

```
<pages>
    <page>
     <id>1</id>
     <name></name>
     <description>&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; target=&quot;_self&quot;&gt;LINK&lt;/a&gt;</description>
     <boxes>
      <box>
      </box>
     </boxes>
    </page>
    <page>
     <id>2</id>
     <name></name>
     <description>&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; target=&quot;_self&quot;&gt;LINK&lt;/a&gt;</description>
     <boxes>
      <box>
      </box>
     </boxes>
    </page><page>
     <id>3</id>
     <name></name>
     <description>&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; target=&quot;_self&quot;&gt;LINK&lt;/a&gt;</description>
     <boxes>
      <box>
      </box>
     </boxes>
    </page>
</pages>
```

This code winkles out the ids and descriptions.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')

>>> for page in tree.xpath('.//page'):
...     page.xpath('id')[0].text, page.xpath('description')[0].text
... 
('1', '<a href="http://google.com" target="_self">LINK</a>')
('2', '<a href="http://google.com" target="_self">LINK</a>')
('3', '<a href="http://google.com" target="_self">LINK</a>')
```

Comment: Just tried this now and I'm getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2287, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (s
rc\lxml\lxml.etree.c:68382)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 359, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__ca
ll__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:173282)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle
_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:171653)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: You've showed us one complete `page` element in your question. Would you also put in the line of xml that precede the first `page` element. Also show us the code you've run that throws this error.

Comment: Sorry it did work using your code above but it's only catching the description directly under page. Ideally what I'm trying to do is get the page ID, it's url, and then I want to find any images that appear in the <description> element within <boxes>  for each page. If I can figure out how to get even the description from each box element along with it's page and URL that would be a great start! I've edited my post above with the full structure of each page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer does what you asked for then you can mark it accepted. I'd be happy to answer another question. Just leave a comment here to let me know you've posted it.

Comment: I posted a new question for the above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078480/how-to-find-all-guide-ids-and-pages-with-img-tags-in-xml-export-with-lxml-xpath