# How to find all guide IDs and pages with IMG tags in XML export with lxml/xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How can I parse the below XML in order to find for each GUIDE, it's ID and UL, then for each PAGE inside GUIDE, the page ID and any images that appear inside BOXES / BOX / ASSETS / DESCRIPTION? The images are in HTML format so I need to grab the source from each image.

```
  <guide>
    <id></id>
   <url></url>
  <group>
   <id></id> 
<type></type>
<name></name>
   </group>
   <pages>
    <page>
 <id></id>
 <name></name>
 <description></description>
 <boxes>
  <box>
   <id></id>
   <name></name>
   <type></type>
   <map_id></map_id>
   <column></column>
   <position></position>
   <hidden></hidden>
   <created></created>
   <updated></updated>
   <assets>
    <asset>
     <id></id>
     <name></name>
     <type></type>
     <description></description>
     <url/>
     <owner>
      <id></id>
      <email></email>
      <first_name></first_name>
      <last_name></last_name>
     </owner>
    </asset>
      </assets>
     </box>
    </boxes>
   </page>
   </pages>
    </guide>
```

This gives me the pages with their ID and descriptions but it's the descriptions inside the asset elements I need to access, and the guide/page they are on.

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
for page in tree.xpath('.//page'):
    page.xpath('id')[0].text, page.xpath('description')[0].text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern of the code is probably similar but I can't check this because I don't have your full xml.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
>>> for guide in tree.xpath('guide'):
...     '---', guide.xpath('id')[0].text
...     for pages in guide.xpath('.//pages'):
...         for page in pages:
...             '------', page.xpath('id')[0].text
...             for description in page.xpath('.//asset/description'):
...                 '---------', description.text
... 
('---', 'guide 1')
('------', 'page 1')
('---------', 'description')
```

I assumed that your xml would have multiple `guide` elements. This is what I parsed.

```
<guides>
    <guide>
        <id>guide 1</id>
        <url></url>
        <group>
        <id></id> 
        <type></type>
        <name></name>
        </group>
        <pages>
            <page>
                <id>page 1</id>
                <name></name>
                <description></description>
                <boxes>
                    <box>
                        <id></id>
                        <name></name>
                        <type></type>
                        <map_id></map_id>
                        <column></column>
                        <position></position>
                        <hidden></hidden>
                        <created></created>
                        <updated></updated>
                        <assets>
                            <asset>
                                <id></id>
                                <name></name>
                                <type></type>
                                <description>description</description>
                                <url/>
                                <owner>
                                    <id></id>
                                    <email></email>
                                    <first_name></first_name>
                                    <last_name></last_name>
                                </owner>
                            </asset>
                        </assets>
                    </box>
                </boxes>
            </page>
        </pages>
    </guide>
</guides>
```

I made life easier for myself by indenting the xml so that I could discern its structure.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll try it now! What are these parts for: '------'?

Comment: The hyphens are to point out that under each guide entry there will be a series of corresponding page entries, and under each of these a series of corresponding description entries.

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected but it's quite hard to read the results. Could you point me in the right direction for figuring out how to output this to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Please ask another question. (Yes, really.) I've never done that. Anyway, I don't have Excel.

Comment: Posted another question as above but for trying to get img sources. Perhaps you could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093335/xpath-for-img-src-within-element/47093979#47093979