# xpath for img src within element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How would I modify the below code so it picks out the source of any images found within the description element, which contains html? At the moment it just gets the full text from inside the element and I'm not sure how to modify this to get the sources of any img tags.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
>>> for guide in tree.xpath('guide'):
...     '---', guide.xpath('id')[0].text
...     for pages in guide.xpath('.//pages'):
...         for page in pages:
...             '------', page.xpath('id')[0].text
...             for description in page.xpath('.//asset/description'):
...                 '---------', description.text
```

I have also tried this at the end:

```
print(description.xpath("//img/@src"))
```

which gives me 'None'

The XML structure is:

```
<guides>
<guide>
    <id>guide 1</id>
    <group>
    <id></id> 
    <type></type>
    <name></name>
    </group>
    <pages>
        <page>
            <id>page 1</id>
            <name></name>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Some text. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;img 
            width=&quot;81&quot; 
            src=&quot;http://www.example.com/img.jpg&quot; 
             alt=&quot;wave&quot; height=&quot;63&quot; style=&quot;float: 
              right;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
            <boxes>
                <box>
                    <id></id>
                    <name></name>
                    <type></type>
                    <map_id></map_id>
                    <column></column>
                    <position></position>
                    <hidden></hidden>
                    <created></created>
                    <updated></updated>
                    <assets>
                        <asset>
                            <id></id>
                            <name></name>
                            <type></type>
                       <description>&lt;img src=&quot;https://www.example.com/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;image&quot; height=&quot;42&quot; width=&quot;42&quot;&gt;</description>
                            <url/>
                            <owner>
                                <id></id>
                                <email></email>
                                <first_name></first_name>
                                <last_name></last_name>
                            </owner>
                        </asset>
                    </assets>
                </box>
            </boxes>
        </page>
    </pages>
</guide>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the `description` element is HTML. There are various ways of parsing it, one of them being `html` from `lxml`.

```
>>> description.text
'<img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" alt="image" height="42" width="42">'
>>> from lxml import html
>>> img = html.fromstring(description.text)
>>> img.attrib['src']
'https://www.example.com/image.jpg'
```

Edit, in response to comment:

```
>>> from lxml import etree, html
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
>>> for guide in tree.xpath('guide'):
...     '---', guide.xpath('id')[0].text
...     for pages in guide.xpath('.//pages'):
...         for page in pages:
...             '------', page.xpath('id')[0].text
...             for description in page.xpath('.//asset/description'):
...                 '---------', html.fromstring(description.text).attrib['src']
... 
('---', 'guide 1')
('------', 'page 1')
('---------', 'https://www.example.com/image.jpg')
```

---

Edit: Handling exception.

Replace

```
'---------', html.fromstring(description.text).attrib['src']
```

with

```
try:
    '---------', html.fromstring(description.text).attrib['src']

except KeyError:
    '--------- No image URL present'
```

Edit, responding to 9 Nov comment:

```
from lxml import etree, html
tree = etree.parse('guides.xml')
for guide in tree.xpath('guide'):
    print('---', guide.xpath('id')[0].text)
    for pages in guide.xpath('.//pages'):
        for page in pages:
            print('------', page.xpath('id')[0].text)
            for description in page.xpath('.//asset/description'):
                try:
                    print('---------', html.fromstring(description.text).attrib['src'])
                except TypeError:
                    print('--------- no src identifiable')
                except KeyError:
                    print('--------- no src identifiable')
```

Output for xml file where 2nd guide element contains no HTML at all, and 3rd contains HTML without a src attribute.

```
--- guide 1
------ page 1
--------- https://www.example.com/image.jpg
--- guide 2
------ page 1
--------- no src identifiable
--- guide 3
------ page 1
--------- no src identifiable
--- guide 4
------ page 1
--------- https://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate this into the for loop?

Comment: If one of the description elements doesn't contain an image URL would this still continue parsing or would it stop? When I run it on my XML I'm getting 'KeyError: 'src'.

Comment: No, you're right, it would fail in that way. If you're asking me what to do, you could enclose that statement that gives rise to the exception in a `try .... except` that captures the `KeyError`. It would be best to capture that error specifically, in case there might be other flaws somewhere that need your attention.

Comment: How would I stop it failing in this way? Would I put an if else telling it to continue if the condition is not met or something? It is definitely only happening when no image links or present, or if the description tag is empty.

Comment: Thanks again, this worked! However, now it is only working if description only contains an image, if there's other HTML content in there as well it fails.

Comment: You can add additional `except` items. Use one that matches the error that occurs when the bigger HTML content is in there (in the same way that I used `KeyError` to match what was in the diagnostic message) and print it, so that you can work out how to deal with it.

Comment: Any idea what this means? I tried to wrap it in a try as above but it just returned empty. File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 875, in froms
tring
    is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Please, show your code as it stands now. You can modify my answer if you like.

Comment: MY code is exactly as yours above with the try ... except added in. If I use only the KeyError exception I get the TypeError, but if I add in the TypeError as well it throws back 'No image URL Present' for all pages, except ones that only contain an img tag and no other HTML content. I've edited the XML above to add in an example of description content that fails to parse.

Comment: Thanks but it still just brings up images that have no other HTML surrounding them. Anything that is surrounded by other HTML returns 'no src identifiable'.

Comment: At this point I've shown you all of the essential techniques. There could be many other variations that you would need to handle in a file of that size.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179641/xpath-to-parse-src-from-img-tag) solution:

```
description.xpath("//img/@src")
```

Comment: This just returns a load of empty []

Comment: I don't understand why description.text gives me the image url as text but description.xpath("//img/@src") returns []

Comment: Different context: But the 'xpath=//img/@src' worked for me to locate the element.